# При нажатии на ссылку выдвигается блок

Tags: html, css, javascript

У меня встал вопрос,как реализовать такую штуку,нажимаешь на ссылку и с правой стороны выходит блок выдвигая сайт в сторону.Тоесть не поверх а просто сайт выдвигает в сторону.Пример можете увидеть на сайте фэйсбук,там кнопка в правом нижнем есть Чат нажимая появляется блок выталкивающий сайт а внутри блока уже нужный мне контент

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Посмотреть красивый пример](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/HrdPe/6/)**

[image: Свернутый чат]

[image: Развернутый чат]

**html**

```
<input id="show_chat" type="checkbox" />
<div class="content">
     <h1>Header</h1>
     <p>Content</p>
</div>
<div class="chat-wrapper">
    <label for="show_chat">Покажите мне чат!</label>
    <div class="chat-content">Успех! :)</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#show_chat {
    display: none;
}
.content {
    background-color: #aaeeff;
    width: 100%;
    transition: width 0.5s;
    -o-transition: width 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: width 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;
}
.chat-wrapper {
    bottom: 0;
    display: table;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
}    
.chat-content {
    height: 0;
}
#show_chat:checked ~ .content {
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
    transition: width 0.5s;
    -o-transition: width 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: width 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;
}    
#show_chat:checked ~ .chat-wrapper .chat-content{
    height: 20px;
    transition: height 0.5s;
    -o-transition: height 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: там у него требование - сдвигать main content сайта влево...

Comment: Уже делаю...

Comment: Все, теперь сдвигается все как надо.

Comment: +1 я чет не додумался input ещё выше перенести :)

Comment: Да я бы и не додумался, но ваше решения для меня послужило вызовом: "А неужели я сам не догадаюсь как по-другому сделать?", - вот и поломал голову, как без табличной верстки сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Верстаешь блок в видимом состоянии, потом прописываешь ему css правило через класс - display: none; а далее с помощью js прописываешь изменение на display: block; при нажатии на кнопку.

Comment: печально то что я js тупиком не знаю

Comment: печально, что вы не зная js беретесь за такое задание, но не беда - это можно сделать на css :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/hVs9p/

Comment: Красота! Опять я, видимо, читал через строчку... Забыл контент сдвигать.

Comment: вот кстати яркий пример где без `<label `**for=**`>` не обойтись

Comment: eicto, во мне это нужно но есть адаптация под оперу?

Comment: @Тахир, сами сделайте адаптацию. :)